# Restoring mariadb backup to docker container

Tags: docker, mariadb

Is there any way we can restore mariadb backup from host to a mariadb docker container.

I am new to mariadb. I don't know about how mariadb backup work.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the backup using [mysqldump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/#mysqldump). You will get a ascii file with lots of instructions to (optionally) remove and recreate the tables, then insert the data. This file can be huge but easily compressed and is very versatile.

When creating a new mariadb container, you can not only have a database created and granted to a specific user but even data loaded automatically. Check out the section Initializing a fresh instance in https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb. There is also an extra section to point out how to create and restore backups from dockerized MariaDB.

Comment: Is there any physical backup you can refer ?

Comment: You may want to read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/#logical-vs-physical-backups